# On the estimation of the average of a deteriministic, scalar, real-valued function of two variables.

Tags: statistics, average, estimation

Suppose we have a scalar, real-valued function of two variables
$F(x,y)$ where ($x$,$y$) belongs to a discrete domain $D$ of $F$, which has finite number of elements. Let $\mid D \mid$ be the number of elements in $D$. One way to define the average of $F$ is as follows:

$$
\text{Average}(F) = \frac{\sum_{\forall (x,y) \in D} F(x,y)}{\mid D \mid}
$$

This calculation is tractable as long as $\mid D \mid$ is not very large; however, I'm dealing with a situation where the size of the domain is exponentially large.

**My question:** how to approximate the average in case of an exponentially large domain?

**My thoughts:** I hope someone criticize its feasibility:

I'm thinking of a Monte-Carlo approach, where I do $k$ rounds of estimations of the average, and then find the average of the averages.

One round of estimation: pick a random $d$, and generates $d$ uniformly distributed pairs from the domain $D$. Sum the function on these pairs, and divide by $d$ to get the round estimation of the average.

After $k$ rounds, we computed $k$ averages: sum them up, divide the result by $k$, which results in the final estimation of the average.

Here are my concerns about my approach:

1. Is my estimation approach (per one round) correct? In other words, does the round average represent a good-enough estimation of the real average?
2. In case this approach is correct, is there a way to measure the approximation error?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is some symmetry in your domain that would allow you to group some similar spaces?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let's say that even when ruling out symmetric pairs, the domain is still exponentially large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of problem can be addressed using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, a Markov Chain Monte Carlo approach.  Care must be taken, however, to avoid situations where a sufficiently pathological function and a poorly chosen proposal distribution could lead to a failure of detecting areas of the function with a large contribution.  In general, MCMC methods can yield better results than naive MC methods if the dimensionality is high (or equivalently, the sample space is extremely large).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm for more details and the principles of implementation.